# How to play, stop, and then play again with MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

My Code:

```
llBtn = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.button);
llBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "LL WAS CLICKED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //IF AUDIO IS NOT PLAYING... PLAY AUDIO... OTHERWISE... STOP AUDIO
        if (tvPS.getText() == "Stop!") {
            StopAudio();
        }
        else {
            PlayAudio();
        }
    }
});

public void StopAudio() {
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        stopPlaying(mediaPlayer);
    }
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "STOPPED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    tvPS.setText("Play!");
}

public void PlayAudio() {
    stopPlaying(mediaPlayer);
    tvPS.setText("Stop!");
    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    inResId = getResources().getIdentifier("myaudio2" , "raw", getPackageName());

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), inResId);
    mediaPlayer.start();
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private void stopPlaying(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
   }
}
```

When I play the audio and stop it in the middle and click on play again, the app crashes with the following logcat:

```
04-06 18:46:48.383: E/AndroidRuntime(13041): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 18:46:48.383: E/AndroidRuntime(13041): Process: com.myapp, PID: 13041
04-06 18:46:48.383: E/AndroidRuntime(13041): java.lang.IllegalStateException
04-06 18:46:48.383: E/AndroidRuntime(13041):    at android.media.MediaPlayer._stop(Native Method)
04-06 18:46:48.383: E/AndroidRuntime(13041):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.stop(MediaPlayer.java:1211)
04-06 18:46:48.383: E/AndroidRuntime(13041):    at com.myapp.MainActivity.stopPlaying(MainActivity.java:131)
04-06 18:46:48.383: E/AndroidRuntime(13041):    at com.myapp.MainActivity.PlayAudio(MainActivity.java:83)
04-06 18:46:48.383: E/AndroidRuntime(13041):    at com.myapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)
04-06 18:46:48.383: E/AndroidRuntime(13041):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
04-06 18:46:48.383: E/AndroidRuntime(13041):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19761)
04-06 18:46:48.383: E/AndroidRuntime(13041):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-06 18:46:48.383: E/AndroidRuntime(13041):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-06 18:46:48.383: E/AndroidRuntime(13041):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-06 18:46:48.383: E/AndroidRuntime(13041):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
04-06 18:46:48.383: E/AndroidRuntime(13041):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-06 18:46:48.383: E/AndroidRuntime(13041):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-06 18:46:48.383: E/AndroidRuntime(13041):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
04-06 18:46:48.383: E/AndroidRuntime(13041):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

How can I resolve the issue.

I would like the ability to play and stop and replay again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram), `stop()` puts the MediaPlayer in a "Stopped" state. Calling `start()` is not allowed in this state, hence the exception.

The only way to play again from this state is to call `prepare` or `prepareAsync`, wait for `onPrepared`, and finally call `start()`.

In contrast, you can `pause()` and `start()` repeatedly.

Since you are playing audio only, it might make sense to replace:

```
 mp.stop();
 mp.release();
```

with:

```
 mp.pause();
 mp.seekTo(0);
```

#### Edit:

I noticed your `PlayAudio` creates a new instance of `MediaPlayer`. If you use the above solution with `pause`, you should create the `MediaPlayer` once (for example in `onStarted`) and not release it until `onStopped`.

Comment: I suggest you just pause and seek to beginning.

Comment: Works for me :) Thanks. I wanted to release it but it will do.